# Como fazer para obter as respostas de um form?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Pessoal eu fiz esse site recentemente mas não sei como obter as respostas que fiz no form.
Alguém pode me ajudar?! Obrigado!

```
<title>Felipe Mellão - Programador Web</title>

<!-- Principal CSS do Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Estilos customizados para esse template -->
<link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Felipe Mellão - Programador Web &nbsp &nbsp</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Início &nbsp <span class="sr-only">(atual)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#autor">Autor &nbsp</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#cursos">Cursos &nbsp</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main role="main">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="first-slide" src="" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
            <h1>PACOTE OFFICE 365</h1>
            <p>Prepare-se para o mercado de trabalho com o curso de Office 365 - Essencial  com Excel, Word, PowerPoint e Certificado.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href=" https://www.udemy.com/pacote-office-essencial/?couponCode=VD0111" role="button">Saiba mais</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="second-slide" src="" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>EXCEL</h1>
            <p>Melhore suas chances no mercado de trabalho, conheça o curso completo de Excel 365.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://www.udemy.com/excel-completo-do-basico-ao-dinamico/?couponCode=EXCCOMP2018" role="button">Clique Aqui</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="third-slide" src="" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1>QUER MAIS CONTEÚDO?</h1>
            <p>Conheça todos os cursos e Promoções!!</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://www.udemy.com/user/wagner-da-silva-cardoso/" role="button">Compre com 50% Desc.</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Voltar</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Avançar</span>
    </a>
  </div>


  <!-- Mensagens de marketing e outras featurezinhas
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Envolve o resto da página em outro container, para centralizar todo o conteúdo. -->

  <a name="autor"></a>
  <div class="container marketing">
    <hr class="featurette-divider"><br><br>
    <!-- Três colunas de texto, abaixo do carousel -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="img/autor.jpg" alt="Felipe Mellão" width="140" height="140">
        <h2>Programador Full-stack</h2>
        <p>Sou programador full stack com grande capacidade de aprender diversas áreas da programação.
          Gosto de ser pró-ativo e produtivo sempre. Amo estudar! Me esforço para ser um grande programador muito
          bem sucedido. Se não possuo conhecimentos que a empresa pede, estudo até aprender e me dedico 24 horas por dia.
          Se você quiser, você pode ver os meus projetos indo para o meu github. 
        </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://github.com/MellonFive" role="button">Ir para o github &raquo;</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->


    <!-- COMEÇAM AS MENCIONADAS FEATUREZINHAS xD -->
    <a name="cursos"></a>
    <hr class="featurette-divider"><br><br>

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">HTML e CSS completo.<span class="text-muted">Aprenda Todos os Segredos do Desenvolvimento Front-end.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Aprenda do ZERO tudo sobre Desenvolvimento WEB  mesmo sem nenhum conhecimento prévio e torne-se um desenvolvedor Front-end.</p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://www.udemy.com/user/wagner-da-silva-cardoso/" role="button">Compre com 50% Desc.</a></p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" src="img/html.png" alt="Curso completo de HTML e CSS">
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Access 365 &nbsp<span class="text-muted">Aprenda do ZERO como criar um Banco de dados Completo.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Ferramenta completa da Microsoft para criação de banco de dados, buscas e registros de informações em Geral.</p>

          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://www.udemy.com/user/wagner-da-silva-cardoso/" role="button">Compre com 50% Desc.</a></p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
        <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" src="img/access.png" alt="Access 365 curso completo" >
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Lógica de Programação <span class="text-muted">Curso completo para Iniciantes.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Aprenda neste curso os principais segredos para iniciar na área desenvolvimento e ganhe um brinde!</p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://www.udemy.com/user/wagner-da-silva-cardoso/" role="button">Compre com 50% Desc.</a></p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" src="img/logica.png" alt="Curso de Lógica de Programação para Iniciantes">
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <!-- /FIM DAS FEATUREZINHAS *-* -->

    <div class="formulario">
        <form name="formteste" action="recebe_dados.php" method="post">
          <h2 style="text-align:center">Preencha esse formulário para eu saber se você gostou do site. O que pode ser melhorado, o que você gostou, não gostou...</h2>

          <p class="nome">
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Informe seu nome" required="required">
          </p>

          <p class="email">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Informe seu e-mail" required="required">
          </p>

          <p class="assunto">
            <input type="text" name="assunto" placeholder="Informe o assunto" required="required">
          </p>

          <p class="mensagem">
            <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Deixe sua mensagem"></textarea>

          </p>

          <p>
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" required="required">

          </p>
        </form>
      </div>

  </div><!-- /.container -->


  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer class="container">
    <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Voltar ao topo</a></p>
    <p>Felipe Castelli Mellão, 2017-2018 &nbsp <a href="#"></p>
  </footer>
</main>

<!-- Principal JavaScript do Bootstrap
================================================== -->
<!-- Foi colocado no final para a página carregar mais rápido -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Só faz o nossos placeholders de imagens funcionarem. Não precisar copiar a próxima linha! -->
<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: no php para pegar nome: `$nome=$_POST['nome'];` para pegar assunto `$assunto=$_POST[assunto'];` etc.....

Comment: Obrigado chapa, obrigado mesmo!